# Doubt in proof of Prime Number Theorem in the book by Apostol

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation, analytic-number-theory

I have been studying the proof of Prime Number Theorem as outlined in the book **Introduction to Analytic Number Theory** by Apostol. I came across the following lemma :

[image: Lemma]

In the proof of this lemma, the author states:

If $z = x + i y$ and $| z |= R$ the integrand is dominated by

$$\left|\frac{u^{-z}}{z(z+1)\cdots(z+k)}\right| = \frac{u^{-x}}{|z||z+1|\cdots|z+k|}$$

I can't understand how $|u^{-z}| = u^{-x}$.

I know this seems like a stupid doubt but please help me understand what I am missing.

Comment: Since $z=x+iy$ but $u^z=u^x\cdot u^{iy}$. But $|u^{iy}|=1$ (remember that $e^{iy}$ has absolute value $1$) so $|u^z|=|u^x|$.

Comment: If it helps, $u^{iy}=e^{i(y\log u)}$ when $u$ is real.

Comment: Aah! Got it... Thank you !